# ERROR: Network "docker_default" needs to be recreated - option "com.docker.network.windowsshim.networkname" has changed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose.exe up` shows

> **ERROR:** Network "docker_default" needs to be recreated - option "com.docker.network.windowsshim.networkname" has changed

after the last Docker update yesterday, under **Windows 10 Pro**. How can I do that?

- Docker version: `17.06.1-ce`
- build: `874a737`

Comment: Is this question related to programming?

Comment: Don't updated to the latest versions when they come. It not always a good practice. If it is working leave it like that. If there is a specific fix in the new version that you want to use then do that. Now uninstall the new version and install the old one